# Why does this XML/XSD combination not export out of Excel 2007?

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, excel-2007, xsd-validation

I'm developing an XML database, and I believe that my Schema and XML are valid. In the distant future when I have this list populated with thousands of different items, I would like to use MS Excel. However, I am unable to properly import or even export a simple XML document.

My Schema is as follows: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27596075/StackOverFlow/Example.xsd
And this is my example XML file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27596075/StackOverFlow/Example.xml

As a rookie Stack Overflow user, I've already exhausted my 2 hyperlinks, otherwise I would have posted some screenshots.

I believe my XSD is vaild because I've had it validated online, and when I include it into MS Excel 2007, I see it properly outlined in the Source Pane.  And when I import my example XML data, I get multiple rows in the Excel sheet of inconsistent mapping.
As a rookie Stack Overflow user, I've already exhausted my 2 hyperlinks, otherwise I would have posted some screenshots.

Once imported, I can't export this data. I'm told by  Excel that
root_Map is not exportable because it contains the following:
--List of lists
--A mapped element's relationship with other elements cannot be preserved.

I believe that this case should be open and shut, but as you can see, I've been proven wrong all the way through. Hours of search have yet to yield a substantial answer, and I would really like to avoid working on this database on CSV or on text editors.
I've read some brief mention of an XSLT but I don't see how an XSLT would help map my XML data to an XML spreadsheet.

Please advise on any workarounds to this problem or if my approach needs improvement.

Comment: I've tried adding an XSLT to this document and was not able to output the XML file into Excel in the expected form. I could still use some help with this. I believe this form would be the best and would like to keep going without changing my schema.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth ...

Your XSD schema document looks OK to me, and Xerces J has no trouble validating with it.

But your XML document is not valid against the schema.  Xerces reports trouble at line 15, where the XML has an `nks` element where the schema is expecting a `kn` element.  (Once I add an empty `nks`, the document is schema-valid against the schema.)

Could some of the problems you're experiencing with Excel be due to the document's not being valid against the schema?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response, C.M..

To be honest, I'm not familiar with Xerces J. I'm limited as to what softwares I can use, hence my using Excel for the project. I can't imagine why Xerces issued that report, though. The way I set up the sequences, `nks` is the parent node of `kn`. The XML file I have just fills the basic elements, so if `kn` is not populated, I'm concerned if Xerces J is also having some issues properly understanding this, especially since `nks` has no individual value.